# How to plot a mermaid figure using DiagrammeR?

Tags: r, graphviz, mermaid, diagrammer

Let's say, I want to plot this diagram using ``:

```
sequenceDiagram
    Alice->>+John: Hello John, how are you?
    Alice->>+John: John, can you hear me?
    John-->>-Alice: Hi Alice, I can hear you!
    John-->>-Alice: I feel great!
```

When you visit the online [mermaid.live](https://mermaid.live/edit#pako:eNptkL9uAjEMh1_FeO3dC9xAValDQWJiQ1ms5HdcpCSGkKhCiHdv7q5sePKf77NkP9iqAw98w7UiWXx7OWeJJlGLr-At-u32Y69TGugHISjNeUeT_pJk0F3r51t4xaykGaEJkiniH51nfUP7xWmL_Wp3tFuMhW7a5j2-oxEIdM6QsuGOI3IU79oVj1kwXCZEGB5a6jBKDcWwSc-GSi16vCfLQ8kVHdeLk_I6-tW8SDqptnKUcGs1nC-aD-ujln89_wC9jmTi) page (the above code and its plot is already plotted), we see that the expected plot is shown:

[image]

I want to reproduce the same figure in `R`, using `DiagrammeR`:

```
library(DiagrammeR)

mermaid("sequenceDiagram
    Alice->>+John: Hello John, how are you?
    Alice->>+John: John, can you hear me?
    John-->>-Alice: Hi Alice, I can hear you!
    John-->>-Alice: I feel great!")
```

[image]

As we can see, I do not get the expected figure.

Comment: Unfortunately DiagrammeR's embedded mermaid.js is a bit old. There is an issue opened about this.  https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR/issues/501 https://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/reference/mermaid.html

Comment: I cannot check from here, but can you double check that naming the argument doesn't sort it? `mermaid(diagram = "sequenceDiagram
    Alice->>+John: Hello John, how are you?
    Alice->>+John: John, can you hear me?
    John-->>-Alice: Hi Alice, I can hear you!
    John-->>-Alice: I feel great!")`